# D3js group bar chart subgroups with 0 value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to do something similar to this [example](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_grouped_basicWide.html) but I'm passing a 0 value to one subgroup. 
so I have a result like this.

[image]

is there a way to make one of the other subgroups have this blank space?, I thought it would be something like this.

```
svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.group) + ",0)"; })
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return subgroups.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })
    .enter().append("rect")
      ///.attr("x", function(d) { return xSubgroup(d.key); })//change this line to the next one 
      .attr("x", function(d) { if (d.value>0){return xSubgroup(d.key); }})
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("width", xSubgroup.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.key); });
```

Comment: Filter out the 0 value data from the data join, then use the index times the bandwidth to place the subgroup instead of the key?

Comment: I have to do that in this line `.data(function(d) { return subgroups.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })`  ?? and then in then in the line i change?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem ?